# Ext.MessageBox.show() doesn't show message

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently learning Sencha Touch from a book. Following the example doesn't work for me:

```
Ext.require('Ext.data.Store');
Ext.require('Ext.dataview.List');
Ext.require('Ext.MessageBox');
new Ext.application({
  name: 'TouchStart',
  launch: function() {
    this.viewport = new Ext.Panel ({
      fullscreen: true,
      items: [{
        docked: 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        ui: 'light',
        items: [{
          text: 'Panic',
          handler: function(){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Don\'t Panic!','Keep calm');
          }
        },
        {
          text:'Greetings',
          handler: function() {
            Ext.Msg.prompt('Greetings!','What is your name?',
            function (btn,text){
              var response = new Ext.MessageBox().show({
                title: 'Howdy',
                msg: 'Pleased to meet you ' + text,
              });
            });
          }
        }]
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

And in particular:

```
new Ext.MessageBox().show({
  title: 'Howdy',
  msg: 'Pleased to meet you ' + text,
});
```

When I run this, only the title shows, no message is shown:

[image: problem]

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
new Ext.MessageBox().show({
   title: 'Howdy',
   message: 'Pleased to meet you ' + text,
});
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much for the fast response.

Why is this not mentioned on the docs ... or anywhere. EVen the examples at sencha.com show 'msg'

Comment: it is. Check http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox-cfg-message under Configs

Comment: myes oke, but this is never used in any examples

Comment: Its cause that MessageBox class its singleton, so you have to force to create a new instance

Comment: I have to agree with @SnK on this one. The Sencha docs are actually quite unhelpful.